# Different creation time of the same tweet because of Time Zones

Tags: twitter

https://twitter.com/rimjhimcse1/status/1075719496030072833

The link/url conatins a tweet which is tweeted at around 5:20 PM IST and when I search the same on twitter after logging out from my profile. The time shows 3:48 AM. Which time zone this time is. Surely not UTC, as I have rechecked it doesn't match with UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the source code of that tweet, we can see

```
<a href="/rimjhimcse1/status/1075719496030072833" title="3:48 AM - 20 Dec 2018">
    <span class="_timestamp"  data-time="1545306488">22h</span>
```

(edited for clarity)

The tweet was sent at 1545306488 seconds [since January 1st 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

That's 2018-12-20T11:48:08+00:00 - or 11:48 UTC.

So, 03:48 would be at UTC-8.  That's the west coast of America - which is where Twitter is based.

Why has it chosen that time? If we look at the user object, we see:

```
'time_zone': None
```

Because the user hasn't specified a timezone, Twitter assumes they are in California.